# 2 Job Offers, one offering more 20% more money, but GUT FEELING telling me to take lower one

Tags: job-offer, career-development, new-job, job-change

I have two Job Offers.

One pays 95k + 19k Bonus(114k) and the other one only pays 77k - no bonus.

The high paying one is going to require me to relocate to a new city, in a new state, the second one is a local company.

Besides salary, both seem fine so far, and offer nice opportunities for growth and learning. They are well known companies, and will look good at my CV.

The first one is a consultant company, the second one is a product company.

The first one is a position as an Software Architect, while the second one as a Developer, which justifies the salary differences. The actual Job Description is similar for both, with some differences in languages, which I am fine with.

My gut tells me strongly to take the low paid one, and join their team. They were very nice to me, and offered an incredible environment. Although they offer less salary, they offer better work life balance, such as 35 holydays, and home office.

It just seems counter intuitive to take the low paid one, but for me it seems natural, easy going - just the right thing to do. (I am coming from a Start up and leaving a high stressful phase of my career where I worked really hard, over nights, and weekends)

Money wise, I can live very well with 77k where I live, but is it good for my career to follow my intuition?

This is a big dilema for me now.

**EDIT**: The bonus in the first offer is variable, and so far only valid for the first year

Comment: Have you researched the cost of living in the city that the higher paying job requires you to move to? If the cost of living is higher, you might not actually get much out of the higher paying job.

Comment: Personally, I pick option “less salary, more time”. I do not mind people picking option “higher salary”. I know it is cliché, but time is one of the most important resource. Time get exponential expensive when we get older. Sure, I envy people working on awesome projects and it is less glamour volunteering in a activity of my daughter kindergarten. But I love what I decided to do. And I do not feeling rushed by life. I met multiple peoples that pick option 1 and they are happy and have better job opportunity then me.

Comment: So, if you are comfortable with both job salary. It is up to you to pick the job that will fit your life.

Comment: Life is not only work, there is family, health and body to take care, and depending on your choices, your spirituality may matter as well. And of course it is also about work. But I think the key question is about following or not intuition, no which job to take.

Answer (score 3):

Consultancy is likely a lot more than 40 hours a week and bonuses are usually for extra income to the company which requires more hours than the regular work week (which is likely already above 40).  A product, although you have surges in hours worked, is usually a lot more stable income for the company which results in more stable income for individual employment.

So, unless you want to move to a big city and dedicate to the fast lane industry and really make a career centered life, then you likely would do better with a local company that has more stability.  This really is a personal career decision though as you won't have the same opportunities with the local one that you would with a consultancy like that as you would likely get a lot more exposure to various technologies and companies through the consultancy.

1. Career focused progression with more dedicated time spent and more money as well as greater diverse opportunities.
2. Stable balanced environment where you can grow and get paid, but will allow you to focus more on personal life as well as professional.

The choice is yours, good luck.

P.S. I personally chose a little of both in my career and the second option was better by far to me, but I can only speak for myself.  Although a note is my career progression is also partly due to the other as well...